# Google Sheets: Conditional Coloring Based on Slope Increase (Acceleration)

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

In Google Sheets, how do you conditionally color cells based on whether the cell's value is accelerating or decelerating?

For example, in the image below, I created four columns: the time, distance, speed, and acceleration. The acceleration is just the second derivative of the distance. How would I conditionally color the background of the distance column based on the acceleration column in Google sheets? I would not like to create separate columns for speed and acceleration, instead, just relying on the distance column itself.

[image: distance, speed, acceleartion]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Format > Conditional Formatting` tool.

First, select a cell in the distance column. We want this to be red or green based on the corresponding acceleration value in the same row.

You want to use a custom formula (bottom option) and then make it read `=Dx>0`
See the recreation I have done. You will need to do this for each value in distance.

[image: sampledata]

Comment: A few things: (1) Is there any way to do this without first creating the acceleration column? (2) Also, any way to turn it into a gradient rather than a single color? (3) Finally, it looks like you need to have a different formula for each cell, any way you can setup something automatic?